# Событие по клику на строке <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, table

Есть таблица, вот кусок:

```
<tbody>
<tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2"><span class="checkbox-custom2"></span></label></td><td>27.04.2017</td><td>28.04.2017</td><td>118725-31521</td><td></tr>

<tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2"><span class="checkbox-custom2"></span></label></td><td>27.04.2017</td><td>28.04.2017</td><td>118725-31521</td><td></tr>

<tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2"><span class="checkbox-custom2"></span></label></td><td>27.04.2017</td><td>28.04.2017</td><td>118725-31521</td><td></tr>

</tbody>
```

нужно чтобы по клику на строке  выбирался чекбокс этой строки. Помогите пожалуйста.

P.S> стиль чекбоксов заменён на свой

Comment: можно сделать на display: table  и div, а tr можно сделать label, тогда никакого js не понадобится.

Comment: Если один из ответов решил Вашу проблему или помог Вам в поиске решения больше других, отметьте его принятым (нажмите повторно, чтобы отменить)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#myTable tr').click(function(e){
  if (!$(e.target).is(':checkbox')) { // игнорировать если кликнули чекбокс
    var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]')
    checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked"));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='myTable'>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2"><span class="checkbox-custom2"></span></label></td><td>27.04.2017</td><td>28.04.2017</td><td>118725-31521</td><td></tr>

<td><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2"><span class="checkbox-custom2"></span></label></td><td>27.04.2017</td><td>28.04.2017</td><td>118725-31521</td><td></tr>

<td><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2"><span class="checkbox-custom2"></span></label></td><td>27.04.2017</td><td>28.04.2017</td><td>118725-31521</td><td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: попробуй кликнуть по самому чекбоксу

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, поправил)

Answer (score 0):

Можно на чистом JS, без jQuery вот так:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table"); // наша таблица
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]; // тело таблицы

tbody.onclick = function(e) { // событие клика по таблице
  e = e || window.event; // событие
  var target = e.srcElement || e.target; // источник события

  if (target.type === 'checkbox') { // если кликнули чек-бокс
    return; // то нам не нужно ничего делать, он сделает все сам
  }

  while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") { // нужен элемент строки TR
    target = target.parentNode; // переходим к родителю
  }

  var cb = target.getElementsByClassName("checkbox2"); // берем чек бокс из строки TR
  cb[0].checked = !cb[0].checked; // инверсия чек-бокса (на противоположное значение)
};
```

```html
<table id='table'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">
          <span class="checkbox-custom2"></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>27.04.2017</td>
      <td>28.04.2017</td>
      <td>118725-31521</td>
      <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">
          <span class="checkbox-custom2"></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>27.04.2017</td>
      <td>28.04.2017</td>
      <td>118725-31521</td>
      <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">
          <span class="checkbox-custom2"></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>27.04.2017</td>
      <td>28.04.2017</td>
      <td>118725-31521</td>
      <td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `cb[0].checked = !cb[0].checked;`

Comment: @lampa, да, лучше написать короче и красивее, дополнив комментарием, чем кучу кода с кучей комментов :) внес правку

Comment: да даже просто выглядит круче :-D

Answer (score 0):

Альтернативным вариантом решения, может быть запрет всплытия события onclick при клике на сам label, в котором лежит checkbox, это позволит избежать проверки на то, куда кликнули в обработчике клика по строке.

```js
var trs = document.querySelectorAll("table tr"); // тело таблицы

Array.from(trs).forEach(tr => {
  tr.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var cb = this.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
    cb.checked = !cb.checked;
  });
  tr.querySelector('label')
    .addEventListener('click', e => e.stopPropagation());
});
```

```html
<table id='table'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">
          <span class="checkbox-custom2">label1</span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>27.04.2017</td>
      <td>28.04.2017</td>
      <td>118725-31521</td>
      <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">
          <span class="checkbox-custom2">label2</span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>27.04.2017</td>
      <td>28.04.2017</td>
      <td>118725-31521</td>
      <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">
          <span class="checkbox-custom2">label3</span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>27.04.2017</td>
      <td>28.04.2017</td>
      <td>118725-31521</td>
      <td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```