# Верхние теги генерируемой таблицы вставляются не туда

Tags: php

Я пытаюсь создать таблицу, которая генерируется в php файле после отправки пользователем формы. У меня есть уже готовая верстка и выглядит это так:

```
<?php
require_once "handler.php";
include "generitem.php";

require('components/header.php');
?>
<section class="search">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="search_title">
            <h2>Поиск информации о фильме</h2>
        </div>
        <form class="search_form" action="index.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInput">Строка поиска:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Enter search string" name="searchStr">

            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Поиск</button>
        </form>


        <table class="search_table">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="search_table_0">

                    <th>Rank</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th class="rate">Rate</th>

                </tr>

                <?php

                if (isset($_POST['searchStr'])) {

                    $key = "k_u2avc8tx";
                    echo "hello";

                    $searchStr = $_POST['searchStr'];
                    $shortInfoUrl = mergeToUrl("ru", "SearchMovie", $key, rawurlencode($searchStr));
                    $shortInfo = getArrayByUrl($shortInfoUrl);
                    $arrayFilms = $shortInfo["results"];
                    foreach ($arrayFilms as $key => $film) {

                        $filmRatingUrl = mergeToUrl("ru", "UserRatings", "k_u2avc8tx", $film["id"]);

                        generHTML($film["resultType"], $film["image"], $film["title"], $film["description"], 10);
                    }
                }

                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</section>

<?php
require('components/footer.php');
?>
```

цикл foreach генерирует сами элементы таблицы:

```
<?php
function generHTML($rank, $image, $title, $description, $rating)
{

?>

    <a href="bigImage/php?name = <?= $title ?>">
        <tr>
            <td class="search_table_position col-md-1">
                <? echo $rank ?>
            </td>
            <td class="search_table_img col-md-2"> <img width="150px" height="150px" src="<? echo $image ?>" alt=""> </td>
            <td class="search_table_title col-md-8">
                <h3 class="name">
                    <? echo $title ?>
                </h3>
                <p>
                    <? echo $description ?>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="search_table_rating col-md-1">
                <i class="fa fa-star" style="color:yellow" aria-hidden="true">
                </i>
                <?echo $rating ?>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </a>


<?php
}
?>
```

Проблема в том, что таблица должна генерироваться в теге  таблицы, то есть после формы "search_form", а у меня получается, что верхний тег ссылки  залезает в форму, и только оставшаяся часть "tr" остается в теге "table".Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?[![Как расставляются теги][1]][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkmmv.png
```

Comment: __Нельзя__ оборачивать `<tr>` в `<a>`, это __невалидно__ с точки зрения разметки. Поэтому браузер делает лишнюю работу и пытается сделать валидно.

Comment: @u_mulder, Убрал ссылку, попробовал обернуть "tr" в "div" c классом "row" и такая же история https://ibb.co/s13zQCf. В итоге получается, что любой верхний тэг пишется в форму, и только внутренняя часть попадает в таблицу

Comment: Вроде бы понял. В тег tbody нельзя ничего вставлять кроме самих элементов таблицы?

Comment: Естественно, ведь это таблица.

Comment: @u_mulder,Прошу прощения за вопрос,если он не в тему, но можете подсказать, как можно сделать вот такую логику:  у меня элемент таблицы есть краткая информация о фильме(название,год,рейтинг), я хочу, что бы при нажатии на какой нибудь элемент таблицы(фильм) пользователя перенаправляло на отдельную страницу, в которой бы уже выводилась полная информация. Я думал,что можно сделать это через ссылку, которая бы запустила скрипт .php и сгенерировала страничку, но идея нерабочая, как оказалось. Как мне лучше это реализовать ? Спасибо

Comment: Вероятно через джаваскрипт - отслеживая клик по элементу `tr`. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660964/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-tr

Comment: @u_mulder,Да, я думал про js. Как "правильнее" сделать: повесить событие на таблицу, при нажатии делать запрос из js к апи(для получения полной инфы о фильме),получить json и передать его в скрипт пхп для генерации странички или никуда не отсылать json и генерить страничку уже силами js?Спасибо