# хочу передать значения из js в скрипт php с перезагрузкой страницы

Tags: javascript, php, html

Есть сайт, который генерируется php скриптом. На нем есть таблица, по нажатию на элемент таблицы js вытягивает ее название. Я хочу послать эту строку(название) в php скрипт, но нужно сделать это так, что бы поведение было как при переходе с одной страницы на другую. То есть открывается новая вкладка(или просто перекидывает туда пользователя без открытия новой вкладки) и страница перерисовывается. Как это можно сделать и как правильно это сделать. Спасибо заранее за помощь.

Comment: Можете добавить пример таблицы и что нужно из нее вытягивать?

Comment: @OliverPatterson, У меня php отсылает запрос к апи, генерирует таблицу с краткой информацией о фильме. Вот такая табличка: https://ibb.co/Df8Ry9R. Я кликаю по элементу таблицы(фильму), js забирает название фильма, отправляет его в скрипт php, тот получает полную информацию  о фильме, обращаясь к апи, и отрисовывает ее на отдельной страничке. Вот как то нужно реализовать вторую часть.

Comment: Можно html код? Он бы больше помог, в написании кода.

Comment: @OliverPatterson,вот там код генерации элементов таблицы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1240179/%d0%92%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%85%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, попробуйте что-то вроде этого:

```js
// Ищем все элементы названия фильма (по нему идет клик)
document.querySelectorAll('.search_table_title h3.name').forEach((element) =>
    {
        // Вешаем обработчик клика на название фильма
        element.addEventListener('click', (e) =>
        {
            // Получаем название фильма
            let title = e.target.innerText;
            let url = `https://example.com/file.php?title=${encodeURIComponent(title)}`;

            // Переходим по ссылке (в текущей вкладке)
            document.location.href = url;

            // Если нужно, чтобы в истории браузера не осталась запись, то используйте строку ниже
            // document.location.replace(url);

            // Если нужно открыть ссылку в новой вкладке, то используйте строку ниже
            // window.open(url);
        });
    });
```

---

Если нужно по клику на другой элемент, напишите конкретнее.

Comment: А потом, как я перейду по ссылке, в $_POST['title'] будет название?

Comment: Скорее в $_GET['title'].

Comment: Понял,благодарю